# How Do I Select Unique Combinations From MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Let's say i have these in my table.

```
Index   Resultant   First   Second
1       Ice         Water       Cold
2       Cold Air    Water       Cold
3       Cold Wind   Water       Cold
4       Hot Air     Volcano     Air
5       Normal Air  Oxygen      Hydrogen
6       Ice         Cold        Water
7       Cold Air    Cold        Water
8       Cold Wind   Cold        Water
```

I want to only display these

```
Index   Resultant   First   Second
1       Ice         Water       Cold
2       Cold Air    Water       Cold
3       Cold Wind   Water       Cold
4       Hot Air     Volcano     Air
5       Normal Air  Oxygen      Hydrogen
```

because the bottom 3 area all duplicates if you flip them around. But i don't want rows 1,2 to be hidden as well because it's also a combination of water and cold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)
from MyTable
group by least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05d8d/2)